# How do historians reference the people alive in a given century?

Tags: phrase-requests

I suspect historians have a more concise way of referencing [[the people alive in the 17th century]] than *people alive in the 17th century*. Do they call them *17th centurians*, for example?

Comment: But once you've established the era, there's no need to refer to the population as 16th century men and women. They become "the population", "the plebes/the common people", "the aristocracy", "the clergy", "the loyalists" etc.

Comment: Whereas the period is referred to as 'seicento', I know of no specific reference for 'the people of'; @Josh61's  answer is the most common usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historians refer to them as the contemporaries/a contemporary of the x century, or the x century contemporaries/an x century contemporary.

[*contemporary*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/contemporary): a person living around the same time.

E.g.

> *How many obscure, unintelligible points, which we judge too easily as incredible, were natural and clear as daylight for the [contemporaries](http://archive.org/stream/bibleandrational03theiuoft/bibleandrational03theiuoft_djvu.txt) of those past ages!*
>
> *Scholars have cited so many reasons - simple and complex - that we have sometimes forgotten what the [contemporaries](http://www.engagingnews.us/select/Thomas-R-R-Cobb.html) of those times observed*.
>
> *Lawyers of the 17th century doubted it and the [contemporaries](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=8qvY8pxVxcwC&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=%22contemporaries+of+the+15th+century%22&source=bl&ots=nQI1W57yhY&sig=hFYDceQRDSV3Snx3L8MU_Q0fFrA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Kut3U_uxH8PWPKeYgfAN&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22contemporaries%20of%20the%2015th%20century%22&f=false) of the 15th century were very careful indeed in defining its legal mature*.
>
> *Which of the following aspects of the Dutch society most impressed 17th century [contemporaries](http://www.teacherweb.com/nc/mountairyhs/howardmayo/chapter13amp14studyguide.doc)?*
>
> *However, only a few of 19th century [contemporaries](http://kbowenmysteries.com/posts/fashion-friday-corsets/) were sounding the alarm about the particular female undergarment.*
>
> *Riis was [a contemporary](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic472155.files/Sample%20Student%20Essays/RiisDraft1.pdf) of the rapid urbanization of the
> late nineteenth century, during which time cities became expanding centers of industry*.

Alternately, one can also refer to contemporaries of a given century as [people contemporaneous to](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=Mmhx14-Z71EC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22people+contemporaneous+to+the%22&source=bl&ots=WE565dJKS9&sig=YS53RkxKXcJDajGjUVQ5jYrBgaU&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=LfV3U9nSO8PsPLqUgegL&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA)..., or [our ancestors/forebears of](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/news/2278914/replies?c=18)...

> [**forebears**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forebear), also spelled *forbears*: ancestors, forefathers.

Answer (score 0):

To refer to people who lived  in [past centuries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:16th-century_people) you may use the following expression:

- 15th-century people
- 16th-century people,  etc.

Comment: How would you reference an unidentified individual who lived in a given century? E.g. *A 15th-century person*. The number of words the example comprises causes the phrase to seem repetitive quickly.

Comment: Yes, a 15th-century man/person/woman etc.